# How is this string encoded?

Tags: encoding

I'm working with a blackbox API with no documentation. It is encoding the string

```
Simba
```

to read

```
730069006D0062006100
```

It also encodes the cleartext

```
Rude Awakening
```

to read

```
72007500640065006100770061006B0065006E0069006E006700
```

Anyone have any idea what type of encoding this is?

Thanks,
YM

Comment: Probably someone on another SE site will have fun to decode them (with much more examples) but StackOverflow is not the right site...

Comment: Sorry, what site would be better? I believe it's a standard encoding though, I already tried base64 but it didn't work.

Comment: You should first try with similar words: "AAA", "AAB", "BAA"...in case you can see a pattern.

Comment: It's standard ascii to hex. Just throw away the two zeroes after every 2 hex chars. As in, the simba one is actually 73:69:6D:62:61 with insterted zeroes in between.

Comment: Ah, and it converts it to lowercase first. Interesting, thanks Luka Horvat! Can you make that an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It outputs in [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16). Two bytes per character, written in hexadecimal form.

`7300` -> `73 00` -> `00 73` -> code point `115`, meaning [`s`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0073/index.htm).

As you can see, it converts the text to lower case (input `S` became `s`).

Comment: add that it converts to lower-case

Comment: It seems so, given there's no `2000` between `6500` and `6100`.

Answer (score 0):

It's standard ascii to hex. Just throw away the two zeroes after every 2 hex chars. As in, the simba one is actually 73:69:6D:62:61 with insterted zeroes in between.

As you mentioned. It first converts to lower case.

Comment: What if the zeroes aren't zeroes, for example if the input contains accented letters?